# Sorry, an error occurs from Instagram API: This endpoint has been retired

Tags: instagram-api

i am using wordpress site with the grid plugin, yesterday the plugin work great, i added new access token, today it start showing me this error

"Sorry, an error occurs from Instagram API: This endpoint has been retired
"

Answer (score 5):

One more sudden change from Insatagram, few endpoints are deprecated immediately,  It's effective from 4th April.
here is list of endpoints are

1) Follows and Relationships

2) Commenting on Public Content

3) Likes

4) User Search

Please see more details here

There is also some change in response of few APIs

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: On some site its still working .Can it be Possible ?

Comment: It only breaks when you are accessing content from someone else's account, not your own

Answer (score 2):

Facebook retired most of Instagram's APIs today along with a lot of other locking-down in order to address privacy leaks. "This endpoint has been retired" (rather than something like "Unauthorized") suggests maybe you were bit by that. You can read more about it [from Facebook](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access).