# Instagram Location API (V1) is unavailable as of now

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram Location API was active even after April 2018, when most other endpoints had become deprecated. However,

Location endpoints suddenly started returning error.

Request:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?access_token=my_access_token

Response:

```
  {'meta': {'code': 400,
  'error_type': 'APINotAllowedError',
  'error_message': 'This endpoint has been retired'}}
```

After checking the official website, I've found that location endpoint sub-section does not even exist:

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Is there an official statement to this? Would this be one of those instant API limitations without any notice?

Or can it be a temporary issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorry, an error occurs from Instagram API: This endpoint has been retired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661515/sorry-an-error-occurs-from-instagram-api-this-endpoint-has-been-retired)

Comment: Above question is not related to my question. Location API have been active even after April 2018, where most other APIs were down.

Comment: If you actually read the duplicate question, the accepted answer links to the Instagram API changelog that says the location API was deprecated Dec 11.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JJJ for pointing,

The API changelog states that Location and Hashtag APIs have become deprecated as of December 11th, 2018.

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/